# XMPP syntax deprecated in swift 3.0

Tags: ios, swift3, xmppframework

My question is that here "body.setStringValue("Message")" is not available in swift 3.0, is there any alternative syntax for passing message ?

```
func xmppStreamDidAuthenticate(sender: XMPPStream!){

let body = DDXMLElement.elementWithName("body") as! DDXMLElement
let messageID = sender.generateUUID()

body.setStringValue("Message")

let completeMessage = DDXMLElement.elementWithName("message") as! DDXMLElement

completeMessage.addAttributeWithName("id", stringValue: messageID)
completeMessage.addAttributeWithName("type", stringValue: "chat")
completeMessage.addAttributeWithName("to", stringValue: "anotheruser@localhost")
completeMessage.addChild(body)

let active = DDXMLElement.elementWithName("active", stringValue: 
  "http://jabber.org/protocol/chatstates") as! DDXMLElement
completeMessage.addChild(active)
sender.sendElement(completeMessage)}
```

Comment: Here i got the solution this issue, we can write like "body.stringValue = "Hello Message!" in swift version

Answer (score 2):

```
let body = DDXMLElement(name: name, stringValue: stringValue)
```

Answer (score 0):

In swift 3.0, use the following code:

```
let receiverJID = XMPPJID(string:"anotheruser@localhost")
let msg = XMPPMessage(type: "chat", to: receiverJID, elementID:"message1")   
msg?.addBody("Hi there!")
stream.send(msg) // Here stream is the XMPPStream
```